# needs to bring items to front using css tricks

Tags: angularjs, css

Please find my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSHmNxnUrzuL8t1BfCUp?p=preview). Here the items under 'Filter Sub Menu' are not fully visible, can any one help me to bring it to front?

My HTML code for the sub-menu:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a href>Filter Sub Menu</a> 
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="filt in savedFilterList "> 
            <a href ng-click="getDataBasedonFilter(filt)"> {{filt.filter_name}}</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: You have an error in your html. You have to give the `href` a value like `href="URL goes here"` Related to your question, your sidebar width is to small for the dropdown to fit. Your question is CSS related so post some CSS code also

Comment: I have updated. But that should not effect the visibility any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.snapjs-left .snap-drawer-left {
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:5;
}
```

One caveat though is that the snap-content is transparent while animating.

To fix this you can just add the properties above, after animation by using snap.js' event callbacks.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, snapRemote, SNAP_VERSION) {
    $scope.snapVersion = SNAP_VERSION.full;
    $scope.name = 'World';

    snapRemote.getSnapper().then(function(snapper) {

        var snapleft = document.getElementsByClassName("snap-drawer-left");
        snapleft = angular.element(snapleft)

        snapper.on('open', function() {
            snapleft.addClass('expanded');
        });
        snapper.on('close', function(){
            snapleft.removeClass('expanded');
        });
    });
    ...
    ...
```

and instead of the above css, use this:

```
.snap-drawer-left.expanded {
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
.snap-drawer-left {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

to have them appear. You can find a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cpH41NWAcOwP3FNarGk?p=preview)

Comment: Could you pleas check your plunker? It does not have the solution of what I requested. In your plunker also the sub menu items are not fully visible.

Answer (score 1):

In angular-snap.css, the class `.snap-drawer-left` needs to be defined as:

```
.snap-drawer-left {
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

You need to override both the overflow and the z-index, but you need a higher z-index than that for `.snap-content`, which is 2.

Comment: Raad, To avoid initial flash type load problem I have used ng-cloak in my project the soon I apply your solution, initial flash type problem is reappearing, even though I ng-cloak is present in my application. Your solution is solving the problem I reported but it is making ng-cloak feature to fail. I am accepting the answer but this note will be helpful to other readers. However @digitaldouble is solving my reported issue and is not breaking ng-cloak feature too. I don't understand the reason why, even though both of your solutions are almost same !!!

Comment: @MadasuK - fine, no problem =)